# Double click x y co-ordinates WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, double-click, e2e-testing, webdriver-io, spectron

WebdriverIO supplies a [`doubleClick()`](http://webdriver.io/api/action/doubleClick.html) command. Unlike some other commands, such as `leftClick()`, `doubleClick()` does not have any x y parameters. I am unable to double click on specific x y positions on one particular component. I would like to do this because a child element should be inserted at the exact double click location.

I have used `moveToObject()` to first move the cursor to a specific location but `doubleClick` does not pick this up. It always double clicks the center of a component.

Also there is no command like 'elementIdDoubleClick`. And, actions have not been implemented yet.

Does anyone have an idea how I can double click on specific x y co-ordinates within a component?

Comment: Just a random guess; what happens when you call `leftClick()` twice?

Comment: Nice out of the box thinking @ChrisG ! I had a little try and it doesn't go but I will mess around some more and report back if it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use `doDoubleClick();` first move to your element and then use doDoubleClick();

```
return this.app.client.moveToObject(element,5,5).doDoubleClick();
```

But make sure **moveToObject**() and **doDoubleClick**() are deprecated.

WDIO will not remove them without releasing an alternative api.

And make sure you use `webdriverOptions: ({deprecationWarnings : false})`
in your app launch config to silent these warnings.

Answer (score 1):

`doDoubleClick()` doesn't seem to work on Chrome for me, and I'm not sure why.  I see ChomeDriver is [implementing actions as I write this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1897).  Once that's done, you'll be able to do:

```
browser.moveToObject(someElement, x, y);
browser.actions().mouseDown().mouseUp().mouseDown().mouseUp().perform();
```

But right now, when I do that with ChromeDriver 2.45, I get:

```
Error: unimplemented command: session/c4dae3dead96649fc7c26f75709257da/actions
```

So if you're not in the far off future, this is what is working for me:

```
function doubleClick(someElement, x, y) {
  let attempt = 0;
  let timeToDoubleClick;
  do {
    browser.moveToObject(someElement, x, y);
    let startTime = Date.now();
    browser.buttonPress(0).buttonPress(0);
    timeToDoubleClick = Date.now() - startTime;
    console.log("Time to double click: " + timeToDoubleClick);

    if (timeToDoubleClick > 500)  {
      console.log("Waiting 10 seconds to allow the CPU to breath / check to see if a tab has opened...");
      browser.pause(10000);

      // In my case I'm expecting a new tab to open
      if(browser.getTabIds().length > 1) {
        // The tab opened!
        timeToDoubleClick = 0;
      }
    }
  } while(timeToDoubleClick > 500 && attempt++ <= 5);

  if(attempt > 5) {
    throw new Error("Could not manage to double click!");
  }
}
```